# history.pushState disappears in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, pushstate

There is a site http://www.pionart.pl which is a good illustration of the problem I have with the current site I develop with almost the same code/CMS

When I enter the site with IE 11, the browser forgets half of the history methods, incl. history.pushState() (you can easily check it by invoking the console with F12 and typing history.)

When I enter http://stackoverflow.com in the same tab, IE suddenly remembers all the methods back.

The question: what is the purpose of the "forgetting"? How to prevent it?

Adam

Answer (score 5):

The problem was

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

It forced IE 11 back to IE9 state, and we have pushState from IE10 up...

A.