# window.history.pushState() is not defined in IE11(Internet Explore), what is the alternative for PushState() in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

When i am using "window.history.pushState" it returns notdefined error is there any alternative for pushstate(), it is working in below IE versions

I send pushstate by checking it is existing in browser

```
    if(window.history.pushstate)
    {
       window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
    }
```

but it returns else statement.

Is there any alternative to send pushstate...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579063/ie11-window-history-pushstate-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-pushst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276143/history-pushstate-disappears-in-ie-11